# Angular: new HttpHeaders returns "normalizedNames":{}, "lazyUpdate":null

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular. I'm trying to debug an error related to using the `login()` function of `@angular/common/http`. So for the snippet below included in `src/app/core/services/_authService.service.ts`

```
async login(username: string, password: string) {

    const headersJwt = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password),
    });
```

I'm getting on the variable `headersJwt`:

> Error: {"headers":    {  "normalizedNames":{},   "lazyUpdate":null
> }}

Is that ok? what that does mean?

I'm on Angular 16

Comment: Do you see this error while executing request? I tried your example with angular 16 and I don't see any errors